# Downloading weather data from the web, cleaning it, and then saving that into a series of comma separated files?

Tags: python, csv

I have been tasked with calculating 2017 monthly average precipitation for four cities in the United
States. I have been provided a file (stations.csv) containing station identifiers for the four cities
as well as a URL for accessing the weather data online. My first task is to create a script the accesses
the monthly weather data for 2017 at each of the stations in the station file and saves the data as
separate files. This will result in a total of 48 files (4 stations x 12 months).

Here is what "stations.csv" looks like:

```
KCASANFR131,37.778,-122.408
KDCWASHI48,38.913,-77.031
IBRITISH359,49.256,-123.245
KNYNEWYO639,40.755,-74.007
```

I am getting data from: www.underground.com

Specifically editing the line:

https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KMDLAURE5&year=2018&month=2&graphspan=month&format=1

My problem is to specifically do this:

Manually create a new directory (right-click, create new folder) in which to save your 48 weather files.
This is good practice since you want to keep your data separate from your scripts. Save each file into
the data directory using the format ­­.csv

Example: KDCWASHI48­-04-­2017.csv

I think I am close to that but not quite saving each month's temperature data. After I have that temperature data I need to save that into a file and then send that file into a directory file that I made.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import urllib


def accessData(Id, Month):
    url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=" + str(Id) + "&year=2017&month=" + str(Month) + "&graphspan=month&format=1"
    infile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    readLineByLine = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    return readLineByLine


f = open('stations.csv', 'r')

for line in f.readlines():
    vals = line.split(',')

    for j in range(1,13): # accessing months here from 1 to 12, b/c 13 exclusive

        data = accessData(line, j)

        filename = "{}-0{}-2017.csv".format(vals[0], j)

        row_count = len(data)

        for i in range(2, row_count):
            if(data[i] != '<br>\n' and data[i] != '\n'):
                writeFile = open(filename, 'w')
                writeFile.write(data[i])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While we're glad to help, please pust some effort into asking a more specific question, not just asking for help to complete a script. You may get some valuable tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can create directories using os.mkdir.

```
import os

os.mkdir('dirname')
```

You can move files using shutil.move

```
import shutil

shutil.move("/path/to/src", "/path/to/dst")
```

Lastly, I suggest you use Python 3.6 and requests. Especially if it s a new project.

```
import requests

def accessData(geo_id, month):
    # id is a built-in function. We don't want to trample those :)
    url = f"https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID={geo_id}&year=2017&month={month}&graphspan=month&format=1"
    r = requests.get(url)

    return r.text.split()
```

Python 2 is quickly nearing its EOL, end of life is planned for 2020, and many packages have already moved to support Python 3